# php regular expression match number with 2 digitis only, no partial number

Tags: php, regex, expression

I have the following problem in php:

I want to extract a number that has two digits only and is not a partial of a longer number.

I'm using `preg_match()` and want to have the number only as the match result.

For example, `"abc53abc"` should return `53`, but `"abc553abc"` should return nothing.

I tried using `"/[0-9]{2}/"`, but with that i get `53` for the first example, but `55` for the second, which is not what i want.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a negative lookahead and a negative lookbehind,

```
(?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\d)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iX8hF3/12)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!\d)` This negative lookbehind asserts that the preceding character must not be a number.
- `\d{2}` Matches two digits.
- `(?!\d)` Negative lookahead asserts that the following character must not be a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/([0-9]{2})/ui",$str,$match);
```